# vsto excel keypress event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, keypress

i am working on a vsto excel project, and i want to capture keypress, and keydown events on the worksheet.

i have tried [globalKeyboardHook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx?display=Print)

but it gives exception, please any one have a solution, please provide guidance in right direction.

i want to capture the cell contents and provide auto suggest feature based on the contents, as the user types in the cell.

thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please tell us how did you use it in your C# vsto workbook application ?i couldn't find way to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve it using the GetAsyncKeyState() WinAPI function, but it would be a bad practice if you need a solid application that needs to work on different environments.

Comment: Hey can you tell us how did you use it in your C# vsto workbook application ?